# Backspace is not deleting selection but extending it to the left (IntelliJ on Linux)

Tags: intellij-idea, centos, pycharm, virtualbox, backspace

I started using IntelliJ IDEA 14.01 on CentOS 6.2 (on a VirtualBox VM on a Windows 7 machine). While selecting code, the [backspace] key is not deleting the selected text. Instead [backspace] extends the highlighted (selected) area to the left exactly as the [arrow left] does it. How can I change this behavior?

Answer (score 57, accepted):

Turn off `Vim Emulation` in the `Tools` menu

Comment: I have the same issue, but I don't see `Vim Emulation` in the Tools menu :-(

Answer (score 1):

You can toggle enabling and disabling of Vim Emulator by just pressing "Ctrl + Altr + V"

Answer (score 0):

There are 2 options, either select the specific line and hold your keypad and then press delete button or turn off the VIM  emulation in the Tools menu.